# CI/CD pipeline and build server

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Have seen the following graph representing Jenkins pipeline:

```
git push --> Git repo --> Jenkins CI server --> Maven build server --> Test server --> Deliver build artifacts --> Deploy
```

Given that is correct, I am struggling to understand how the above different(?) servers work under the hood and I need some clarification so that Jenkins procedures are not just a black box.

1. `Jenkins CI server`, `Maven build server` and `Test server` are in reality one physical server?
2. If the answer to the previous question is yes, these 3 servers are different logical servers?
3. In my understanding and my case (**Java Spring project**), Maven build server executes `mvn install` and since `pom.xml` contains `npm install` plus `npm run test` commands, it is Maven build server that executes the UI tests and not the Test server. Am I right?
4. Does the Test server execute only the back-end Java acceptance tests?

Comment: 1. We don't know. 2. We don't know, they could all be running on the host or in separate VMs. 3. We don't know, but probably your "test server" is a deployment environment for testing purposes, in which case yes because the test server doesn't execute any tests. 4. We don't know, but in the same case no because the test server doesn't execute any tests. Please cut this down to one clear question with some context. You should probably start by asking whoever set up that pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

1. It could be one physical or virtual server server.
2. no
3. To use maven you just need to install maven plugin in jenkins. Configure which version of maven you want to use in "Manage jenkins" -> "Global tools configuration" -> add needed maven version.
4. Depends on which kind of tests you want to run - you can repeat steps from step 3 for the tool you need or you can install needed tools on the jenkins server manually and add it to the PATH.

At the end just use needed tools in your pipeline or other king of job in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Without further context, we must put some points clear:

- Jenkins may work on multiples nodes (could be real/virtual/pods)
- Jenkins is an orchestrator... This means that it uses different tools in a order given by the pipeline. This order is pretty much: git > build > test > delivery > deploy
- Testing server are used for install the software an run a variety of tests, pretty much for several teams.
- Build servers are used for running commands to build software

With those clear, these are the questions:

1.- Depends on your infrastructure. Jenkins works with executors that may run on master or in nodes. If your Jenkins is just one server, then yes... It is one physical server. If you use nodes, then it is more probable than you may found one node handling the building, and another one the tests. The definite answer lies within your Jenkins and your pipeline

2.- No... Even with a Jenkins master-agent infrastructure, the building and testing occurs within Jenkins.

3.- Depends on your concept of test server. If you define it as a server where you use as a target for testing purposes, then the answer is no... If you define a test server as a machine that executes test, then the answer is yes.

4.- Depends on what you type or test do you have automatized. You can run unit tests, regression tests, smoke test, etc. For example, you may have some unit test for your back-end, and have some test in karma for your UI. Again, in your case you must check on your pipeline, and the code to check what kind of tests are you running.